# Lag function to calculate a value in back day

Tags: r, lag

I update the questions with data. I hope it's a proper question.
Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1dw3.png)i.stack.imgur.com/NAlpL.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Maybe you can post a runnable code and a data sample so we can help ... look at the guidelines on posting for orientation.

Comment: I added. Please check it.

Comment: I cant T___T the system does not allow me

Answer (score 1):

**1) diff**  Base diff can do that:

```
x <- 1:10
c(rep(NA, 4), diff(x, 4))
##  [1] NA NA NA NA  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

**2) collapse::flag**

```
library(collapse)

x - flag(x, 4)
##  [1] NA NA NA NA  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

**3) dplyr::lag**  This has the disadvantage that it overwrites base lag in an incompatible way so we exclude it and then specifically access it.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))

x <- 1:10
x - dplyr::lag(x, 4)
##  [1] NA NA NA NA  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: I tried but it said that : Error in diff.default(combinations$BTC, lead_time) : 
  'lag' and 'differences' must be integers >= 1
> In fact, there is some times that the difference < 0 due to exchange rate fluctuations

Comment: for lag, the error is `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not a double vector of length 60.

Comment: The code above works and does not give any errors.  If you are referring to something else that you have done but not shown in a way that we can reproduce then it is not really possible to know what errors you have introduced.  Suggest you read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page about how to ask a question.